# Get artist name and song name by YouTube code

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

On my website, people are able to drop their YouTube code link Like `faXwJ9TfX9g`

How do I get the name of the artist and name of the song, with a simple Javascript.

```
Input  :  faXwJ9TfX9g   by User
Output :  Name of artist
Output :  Name of the Song
Output :  Length of the Song
```

Best regards,

Simon Buijs
Zwaag Netherlands

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Great first question.

Comment: Feel free to upvote [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/181347378) if you want to see this feature added.

Answer (score 5):

Youtube videos don't have tags for artist and song title (like mp3 files do, for example).
So, AFAIK the best you can do is get the video title. You could go further and parse it to get the artist and song name, but I don't think this is something you'd want to do.
Using the [Data API](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api) here's what you can do:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function processData(data) {
    var title = data.entry.title.$t;
    var duration = data.entry.media$group.media$content[0].duration;
  }
</script>
</head>
  <body>
    <script 
      type="text/javascript" 
      src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/faXwJ9TfX9g?alt=json-in-script&callback=processData">
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This article has a complete answer, including a second version using user selected IDs at runtime (most examples I found seemed to only have a hardcoded ID).

http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2010/01/retrieve-youtube-video-title.html